# Separating out component references into separate files in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to create a typescript file of all component references to use in different modules like the app module and app-routing module to avoid duplication?

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header.component';
import { BreadcrumbComponent } from'./components/breadcrumb.component';
```

Up want to just be able to do something like this

```
import from '/components'
```

Comment: yes you should be using barrel files. `export * from '....'` and have it named `index.ts` and import from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create file `.components/index.ts`

**index.ts**

```
export * from './components/header.component'
export * from './components/breadcrumb.component'
```

Now you can use as:

```
import {HeaderComponent,BreadcrumbComponent } from './components'
```

Comment: this was my comment

Comment: Thanks bluray any ideas why I can only get it to for is I explicitly reference the index file i.e. from '/components/index' rather than just './components'

Comment: yes but i showed complete example. I think this is more illustrative for beginners.